# Running ArcGIS Model tool from Python script?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder

I've broken a complex task down to a very simple exercise and still can't get it to work... **I need to set up a Python Script to Run a Model**.

- model: "SelectTest"
- toolbox: "INTEGRITY_TOOLS.tbx".
- location: c:\Work\INTEGRITY\INTEGRITY_TOOLS.tbx

```py
import arcpy
arcpy.ImportToolbox (r"c:\Work\INTEGRITY\INTEGRITY_TOOLS.tbx", "SelectTest")
arcpy.SelectTest()
```

Comment: You're setting the alias as SelectTest, but what is the model's name? SelectTest? The easiest way to get the right call is to import the toolbox as you are (importtoolbox) in the Python window, then start typing arcpy.Sel... and the intellisense will show you. probably going to be arcpy.SelectTest_SelectTest()

Comment: Instead of `arcpy.SelectTest()` try `arcpy.SelectTest_SelectTest()` if your tool's name is also `SelectTest`.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @Matthew](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78682/running-arcgis-model-tool-from-python-script#comment108182_78682), they:

> had to add a Label in the Alias box within the Toobox and get the
>   order right on the 3rd line: `arcpy.SelectTest_IntegrityTools()`